# I know PHP's read, write, and append... but can you insert? or remove last line?

Tags: php, xml, insert, append

I am trying to create an XML file, but the XML file needs to be wrapped in nodes...  hence, not easy to use append.

Any help with this would be great!!

My XML consists of 2 different node types:

```
<entry id="1_0">
    <title>This is the title</title>
    <description>This is the description...</description>
    <subName>Publishers Name</subName>
    <date>Saturday, June 11th, 2007, 5:46:21 PM</date>
    <BorF>bug</BorF>
</entry>

<vote id="1_0">5</vote>
```

And I've a simple testing page using jQuery to send data (currently static) to a PHP file

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>


<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>

<script>

$(function(){


    $("#addVote").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "saveListData.php",
            data: 'url=bugs_features_listdata.xml&listData=\n<vote id="1_2">3</vote>',
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            success: function(data, textStatus) {
                if (window.console) console.log(textStatus);
            },
            complete: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus){
                if (window.console) console.log(textStatus);
            }
        });
    });

    $("#addEntry").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "saveListData.php",
            data: 'url=bugs_features_listdata.xml&listData=\n<entry id="1_1">\n\
\t<title>This is the title 1</title>\n\
\t<description>This is the description...</description>\n\
\t<subName>Publishers Name</subName>\n\
\t<date>Saturday, June 11th, 2007, 5:46:21 PM</date>\n\
\t<BorF>bug</BorF>\n\
</entry>',
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            success: function(data, textStatus) {
                if (window.console) console.log(textStatus);
            },
            complete: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus){
                if (window.console) console.log(textStatus);
            }
        });
    });


}); 

</script>

</head>

<body>


<a id="addVote" href="#">ADD VOTE</a><br /><br /><a id="addEntry" href="#">ADD ENTRY</a>


</body>
</html>
```

...that currently appends it to my XML file,  but I need the beginning/ending nodes.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to take a piece of $content and wrap stuff around it, like $content = '<node>' . $content . '</node>'; and then put it back in a file? You want to be able to remove those beginning and ending node as well I suppose?

Comment: Do you use an xml library like SimpleXML?

Comment: I've updated my post with some more information...

@tomzx
Say, I currently have an xml file with a bunch of the nodes described above all nicely wrapped in a root node (something like <xml></xml).  I want to add/append a child node (one of the two listed above) within the root nodes.

@txwikinger
I am not currently using an xml library. I'm not very familiar with how they work...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

txwinger had the right idea in his comment on your question. You should use one of PHPs many built-in XML manipulation libraries to add the node, then serialize it and save it as a text file. In [SimpleXML](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php), for instance:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('test.xml');
$vote = $xml->addChild('vote', '5');
$vote->addAttribute('id','1_0');
$fp = fopen('test.xml', 'w');
fwrite($fp, $xml->asXML());
fclose($fp);
```

There are [other XML manipulation libraries](https://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php) that might suit your task better

Comment: Do I need to "install" any of these libraries as I don't think I have access to do so on our current server.

Comment: Probably now. SimpleXML is included by default in all 5.0 + versions of PHP. XMLWriter (another option) is included by default in all 5.1.2+ versions. Your sysadmin might have turned these off, but I doubt it.

Comment: Oops make that "probably not".

Comment: Great!  phpinfo says I've got 5.2.6, so I'll give it a shot.  Thanks!

Comment: Is there syntax to give it (add a child node) a single, entirely filled node as a string for it to add (passed to the PHP function by jQuery), versus passing all the variables and building the node in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

I would say it depends on the structure of you XML document. If the “rest” is predictable, you could cut that part from your file, append the new data and paste the “rest” back:

```
      ⋮
n-1:     <node>last node</node>
n  :  </root>


      ⋮
n-1:     <node>last node</node>
n  :     <node>new node</node>
n+1:  </root>
```

Comment: @Gumbo
I think that is exactly what I am trying to do...  how would one go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to do this the quick and dirty way:
If you open the file in "r+" and set the pointer to a blank line between the last element and the end of the file, it will write over the root level elements closing tag, so just add it back after you write the new child element.  Bear in mind I have been writing php scripts for all of 4 hours, so there is probably a better way, but this is the simplest I've come up with in my 4 hour career.

```
$name = $_POST["name"];
$phone = $_POST["phone"];

$fh = fopen("xml-test-1.xml", "r+");
if (!$fh)
{
    die("Failed to open");
}

fseek($fh, -11, SEEK_END);
fwrite($fh, "<person> \n");
fwrite($fh, "<name>$name</name> \n");
fwrite($fh, "<phone>$phone</phone> \n");
fwrite($fh, "</person> \n");
fwrite($fh, "</people> \n");
fclose($fh);

echo "now look and see if anything was added";
```